# Request / response to Soap API in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, soap

I need to request some data from a SOAP API webservice (XML) in a Rails 4 app. The user inputs his email and confirmation number and receives a bunch of information about his booking.

This was working in a separate app I created without specifying proper routes and using `<%= form_tag(root_url, :method => :get ) %>` in the index view. The finished app will need a proper route structure but I can't get any response from the Soap API when I put `<%= form_tag('searches/show', :method => :get ) %>` in the view for my new app. (I'm just getting a blank screen whereas the old version worked fine)

Currently I'm routing from index to a show page using a hardcoded string. I know this probably isn't the best practice, but since this is calling information from a Soap API, there doesn't need to be a database behind the Rails app. (Even though I've put one in anyway)

Anyway, thanks in advance for your help, here's all the sections of my app which I think are relevant for now. Give me a shout if you need more info!

Index View (/views/searches/index.html.erb):

```
<h1>Manage your Booking</h1>

<p>
  <%= form_tag('searches/show', :method => :get ) %>
  <%= label_tag 'Confirmation Number:' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :confirmation_number %>

  <%= label_tag 'Email:' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email %>

  <%= submit_tag "Lookup", name: nil %>
</p>
```

Show View (/views/searches/show.html.erb)

```
<% if @search %>
  <dl id ="reservation_info">
    <dt>Test Text:</dt>
    <dd><%= @search.reservation_id %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.dining_date_and_time %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.size %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.session_id %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.first_name %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.last_name %></dd>    
    <dd><%= @search.confirm_number %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.allowed_to_cancel_online %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.restaurant_phone_number %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.restaurant_id %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.restaurant_name %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.location_id %></dd>
    <dd><%= @search.location_name %></dd>
  </dl>
<% end %>
```

Controller (controllers/searches_controller.rb)

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
    def index   
      if params[:confirmation_number] && params[:email]   
        @search = Search.new params[:confirmation_number], params[:email]
      end
    end

  private 

    def search_params
      params.require(:search).permit(:confirmation_number, :email)
    end

end

Routes config file:

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :reservations do
  end

  resources :searches do
  end

end
```

Model (models/search.rb):

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :reservation_id, :dining_date_and_time, :size, :session_id, :first_name, :last_name, :confirm_number, :allowed_to_cancel_online, :restaurant_phone_number, :restaurant_id, :restaurant_name, :location_id, :location_name

def client
  client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://wsdl-example-url-placeholder?wsdl", follow_redirects: :follow_redirects)
end

def initialize(confirmation_number, email)
  message = {'ConfirmationNumber' => confirm_number, 'EMail' => email  }
  response = client.call(:search_for_reservation, message: message)
  if response.success?
    data = response.to_array(:search_for_reservation_response, :reservation).first
    if data
      @reservation_id = data[:@id]
      @dining_date_and_time = data[:dining_date_and_time]
      @size = data[:size]
      @session_id = data[:session_id]
      @first_name = data[:first_name]
      @last_name = data[:last_name]
      @confirm_number = data[:confirmation_number]
      @allowed_to_cancel_online = data[:allowed_to_cancel_online]
      @restaurant_phone_number = data[:restaurant_phone_number]

      data2 = response.to_hash[:search_for_reservation_response][:reservation][:restaurant]
      if data2
        @restaurant_id = data2[:@id]
        @restaurant_name = data2[:name]

        data3 = response.to_hash[:search_for_reservation_response][:reservation][:restaurant][:location]
        if data3
         @location_id = data3[:@id]
         @location_name = data3[:name]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Terminal output:

```
Started GET "/searches" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 14:39:56 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by SearchesController#index as HTML
  Rendered searches/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 296ms (Views: 285.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/searches" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 14:39:56 +0100
Processing by SearchesController#index as HTML
  Rendered searches/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 47.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/searches/show?utf8=%E2%9C%93&confirmation_number=ZANHJW5U&email=myemail%40email.com" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 14:40:06 +0100
Processing by SearchesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "confirmation_number"=>"ZANHJW5U", "email"=>"myemail@email.com", "id"=>"show"}
  Rendered searches/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 49ms (Views: 48.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem when routing to other pages such as a show page. When just setting the searches/index as the root and specifying in view (root_url, :method => :get) it works fine. Active Record doesn't impact on it at all. Why is soap request not working when I try to route to another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making a request to a `searches/show` page however you don't have an action for that? You have an action for index, so change the form to make a request to just `searches`. Does that fix it?